# why there is default value argument in preference

Tags: android

when we want to get value of a key we should do something like this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String syncConnPref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN, "defVal");
```

in getString document wrote.

```
  /**
     * Retrieve a set of String values from the preferences.
     * 
     * <p>Note that you <em>must not</em> modify the set instance returned
     * by this call.  The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed
     * if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.
     *
     * @param key The name of the preference to retrieve.
     * **@param defValues Values to return if this preference does not** exist.
     * 
     * @return Returns the preference values if they exist, or defValues.
     * Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name
     * that is not a Set.
     * 
     * @throws ClassCastException
     */
```

now i have a question why default value argument must exist!?

Answer (score 1):

Because the preference may not have been saved yet.  It's easier to deal with this than to write:

```
String value;
if (sharedPreferences.contains(PREFS_KEY)) {
   value = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFS_KEY);
} else {
   value = "defaultValue";
}
```

Comment: ok in fact my problem it is. why android programmers do it in getString()!? it is not duty of android check this preference exist or not. it is duty of application developer

Comment: Somebody somewhere has to make the check eventually. There's pretty much no getting around it, so the API designers thought it would be helpful to include a method that provides a default. Preferences are a good use-case for this because 99% of the time, there *has* to be a default value.

Comment: Say your app had 100 preferences, which way do you think would be easier to read?

Comment: it is very wrong!!!! because it is not relate to api designer. if you want to think in this way a lot of thing must included in api. if someone had 100 preferences he must refactor his code and write a function like you wrote above.

Comment: @rezachess: Actually, if you want a more detailed answer as to *why* someone would include this, you may get some good answers here:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.  It's intended for questions like *why* questions like this.  StackOverflow is more intended for *how* questions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the documentation. What if you call

```
String syncConnPref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN, "defVal");
```

before saving any value? It will have to return `null`, which in turn can create problems like `NullPointerException`. So, default value is used as a precaution.

Comment: ok this is true but i think who write application must to check it and this solution is not good idea.